# How to split string separated by a comma within the bracket

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to split a string separated withing a bracket

for example, I have this string:

```
2021_02_25_{1,2,3,4}_stackoverflow
```

I want to extract the string inside the brackets {} and then split it by comma
so the output would be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use String's [`find`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_find.asp) method:

```
In [68]: s = '2021_02_25_{1,2,3,4}_stackoverflow'

In [75]: s[s.find("{")+1:s.find("}")].split(',')
Out[75]: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

**If you want an `integer` list**:

```
In [77]: list(map(int, s[s.find("{")+1:s.find("}")].split(',')))
Out[77]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `re.findall` here:

```
inp = "2021_02_25_{1,2,3,4}_stackoverflow"
matches = re.findall(r'\{(.*?)\}', inp)
output = [x.split(',') for x in matches]
print(output)  # [['1', '2', '3', '4']]
```

Note that this answer is robust to there possibly being more than one `{...}` term in the input string.  If not, then just access the first element of the 2D list `output` above to get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `regular expression`

```py
import re

s = '2021_02_25_{1,2,3,4}_stackoverflow'
output = [int(i) for i in re.findall(r'{(\d(?:,\d)+)}', s)[0].split(',')]

print(output)
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```